# How do you run Nginx on port 8080 and Apache on port 80 on the same box?

Tags: centos, nginx, port, node.js

I want to install Node.js on my box (CentOS 5) for testing and sandboxing but I can't uninstall Apache as recommend by developers using Nginx.

So what I'd like to do is have Nginx serving

```
nodejs.sandbox.net on IP 10.10.10.10
```

and Apache running (usual setup)

```
sandbox.net on 10.10.10.10
```

and then on my windows host file do something like

```
sandbox.net 10.10.10.10:80
nodejs.sandbox.net 10.10.10.10:8080
```

and by the way how do I install Nginx on CentOS 5 yum?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Just do it. Set the port of nginx to 8080 and here you go. But you can't assign a port to a DNS name. This is not possible.

Comment: haha ok just install it! its not going to create some conflict when I install nginx too eh?

Comment: No. No problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use apache proxy to port 8080 for you. Set nginx to listen on port 8080. Create a virtualhost that will respond to the name nodejs.sandbox.net and set it up as a proxy for port 8080.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName  nodejs.sandbox.net
        ProxyRequests Off
        <Proxy *>
                Order deny,allow
                allow from all
        </Proxy>
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / http://sandbox.net:8080
        ProxyPassReverse / http://sandbox.net:8080
        ProxyErrorOverride Off
        ErrorDocument 404 /notavail.html
</VirtualHost>
```