# nginx on :8080 pointing to all domains

Tags: nginx, virtualhost

ive installed redmine on a subdomain per the instruction here > http://library.linode.com/web-applications/project-management/redmine/ubuntu-10.04-lucid
Its actually not working yet but another story.

my main concern is anytime i go to anything.domain.com i get directed to the same thing, (redmine/nginx).

what throws me off is if i have a subdomain running/created with virtualmin, that works ok. it just seems like port 8080 is a catchall, where i prefer that the catchall is apache at port 80 so it can say "you dont have permission".

here is my virtualhost (ive also used localhost:8080 instead of the domain name, doesn’t seem to make a difference.

```
<VirtualHost 50.116.11.1:80>
 ServerAdmin me@me.com
 ServerName proj.domain.com

 ProxyPass / http://proj.domain.com:8080/
 ProxyPassReverse / http://proj.domain.com:8080/

 # Uncomment the line below if your site uses SSL.
 SSLProxyEngine On
</VirtualHost>
```

or maybe im looking in the wrong place to do this??
thanks!

Comment: Well you reversed the normal order of things, usually `nginx` proxies to Apache because it does not block on network interaction and handles low connection speed clients much better. Consider moving Apache behind nginx.

Answer (score 1):

not sure which is better, both seem to work, although according to [another answer here](https://serverfault.com/questions/304999/how-do-you-run-nginx-on-port-8080-and-apache-on-port-80-on-the-same-box), this is the correct way

```
<VirtualHost 111.11.1.1:80>
        ServerName  sub.domain.net (one i want nginx on)
        ProxyRequests Off
        <Proxy *>
                Order deny,allow
                allow from all
        </Proxy>
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / http://domain.net:8080 (all other, i want apache on everything except sub)
        ProxyPassReverse / http://domain.net:8080
        ProxyErrorOverride Off
        ErrorDocument 404 /notavail.html
    </VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

correct, thanks alex.

ive changed the proxy pass to port 80

so now i have this in /etc/apache2/sites-available/sub.domain.net and everything except the specified domain go to port 80

```
<VirtualHost 50.111.11.1:8080>
 ServerAdmin me@me.com
 ServerName sub.domain.net

 ProxyPass / http://localhost:80/
 ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:80/

 # Uncomment the line below if your site uses SSL.
 # SSLProxyEngine On
</VirtualHost>
```